# React: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: connect: connection refused

Tags: reactjs

I have just started with react and once I ran npm start for the first time, it gave me this issue.

Going through a few of the answers, I found one which mentioned to allow the use of port 3000 i.e. unblocks it by firewall. But no luck yet.

Comment: Show some of your code that is related to the issue ?

Comment: I had just run the command: create-react-app myproject and ran it. That's it. I didn't write any code at all

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. After wandering around for a while i realized i had a VPN running :3 disabling that solved the problem. Maybe check if you have any extension or anything that works as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I am not sure the 'why' behind this. It is working on chrome but not on firefox for some reason. This is weird

Answer (score 0):

**That error appear when you have a running VPN, please disable it and you are good to go**
*That is how i corrected it on my end*